# Android Bluetooth LE Masked UUID Filter

Tags: java, android, filter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am playing around with an experimental `Bluetooth LE` program for Android and iOS, and right now I am having some trouble on the Android side filtering beacon advertisements sent out by the iOS side. Android has a feature to filter advertisements by UUID with a mask (I need this as I am trying to get UUIDs beginning with a specific value) but I can't get it to work. Here's what I am trying:

```
private void freshen() {
    // kill current scanner
    if (mLEScanner != null)
        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

    // set new one to be a match scanner
    ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .build();

    List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();

    // create data uuid starting with the value 1
    ParcelUuid data = ParcelUuid.fromString("10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
    // create a mask to ensure only that value is searched
    ParcelUuid mask = ParcelUuid.fromString("10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");

    // build the filter
    ScanFilter.Builder builder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
    builder.setServiceUuid(data, mask);
    ScanFilter filter = builder.build();

    // add the filter to the scanner
    filters.add(filter);
    mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
}
```

It is producing zero results. Even if I set all mask values to 0 (which is the number for ignore) it still produces zero results. When I remove the filter, plenty of results beginning with 1 appear. Is this broken in the current version of Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a fix for this problem, but I decided to filter by DeviceName instead, as this can be populated by both the Android and iOS sides. Right now I am focusing on iOS to Android communication =>

iOS:

```
func centralManager(_: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi: NSNumber){

    delegate?.didDiscoverPeripheral(peripheral)
    let splitUp : [String] = "\(advertisementData)".components(separatedBy: "\n")
    if (splitUp.count > 1)
    {
        var chop = splitUp[1]
        let counter = chop.characters.count - 2
        chop = chop[0..<counter]
        let chopSplit : [String] = "\(chop)".components(separatedBy: "\"")

        if !(chopSplit.count > 1 && chopSplit[1] == "Device Information" && !sending)
        {
            let hexString = chop[4..<7] + chop[12..<19] + chop[21..<26]
            let hexArray = [hexString[0..<1], hexString[2..<3], hexString[4..<5], hexString[6..<7], hexString[8..<9], hexString[10..<11], hexString[12..<13], hexString[14..<15], hexString[16..<17]]
            let charArray = hexArray.map { Character(hexToScalar(char: $0)) }
            let string = String(charArray) as String
            if (string == "GoTcHa" + stringify(number: writing))
            {
                writing += 1
                let messageUUID = StringToUUID(hex: String(writing) + "hello" + String(writing))
                peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
                let name = String(writing) as NSString
                peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [CBUUID(string: messageUUID)], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: name])
            }
        }
    }
}

func StringToUUID(hex: String) -> String
{
    var rev = String(hex.characters.reversed())
    let hexData: NSData! = rev.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) as NSData!
    rev = hexData.toHexString()
    while(rev.characters.count < 31) {
        rev = "0" + rev;
    }
    rev = String(writing % 10) + rev[0..<30]
    let finalString = rev[0..<7] + "-" + rev[8..<11] + "-" + rev[12..<15] + "-" + rev[16..<19] + "-" + rev[20..<31]
    return finalString
}
```

And more importantly the Android scanning method, which now ignores duplicate messages from iOS by always looking for the next message through the DeviceName:

```
private void freshen() {
    if (mLEScanner != null)
        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
    ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT)
            .build();

    List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();

    ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setDeviceName("" + (reading % 10))
            .build();

    filters.add(filter);

    mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
}
```

I need to get the iOS side to filter Android's responses better now, but it is effective on the Android receiving side.